magento installation with composer timeout
When I want to install the latest version of Magento 2 I always have timeout.
The message is the following one. Each time I have this timeout on the same package at (26%) sebastian/phpcd (6.0.3)
"A connection timeout was encountered. If you intend to run Composer without connecting to the internet, run the command again prefixed with COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 to make Composer run in offline mode."

After this message the download continue to try to install other modules but it's incredibly slow. to reach the last 70% missing 100% it last nearly 1 hour and after that at 100% I have an error message.

curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/framework/magento-framework-103.0.7.0-patch3.zip:
Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 2883114 out of
3804309 bytes received

and nothing is installed.
Here are the actions I tried:
set COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT to 2000 directly in config or in argument nothing change.
I have tried to use the option --prefer-source, --prefer-dist, --no-dev
Nothing changes. I tried to clear composer cache also nothing changes.
I tried everything during days but, when I went to the office, I tried again and surprise! I could install magento 2 without timeout. The installation has last max 5 minutes. and more interesting, when I came back at home, I tried to use my mobile WiFi connection and surprise again! no more problem. installation time : 5 minutes.
I normally use the WiFi. So I tested with my box with wired connection and always a timeout.
So I am now sure that it comes from my internet box. For info I have the fiber. And I use my connection everyday, I didn't notice any problem with any other tools.
I tried to changed the DNS (google 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4 ) cloudflare (1.1.1.1) nothing changes.
I didn't see any firewall with my freebox. I don't understand what could generate this timeout. What is surprising is that it is at the start of the installation everything seems to be fast and ok, and arrived on this package (after 10 scdes of good speed download ) it become very very very slow. It's not the package who cause this issue because I tried to make a composer install on an other version of magento and I had same issue. It's my internet box.
If someone has already experienced that I would be glad to have a feedback.
Thanks

If this is working when using another network, it's not a programming issue

I sent out in parallel a message to my internet provider to see if they have any clues.

You can close the question. I created my own VPN on my VPS to reslove this issue. I think, as mentioned  Nico, the issue come from my box. My internet provider could not bring me any solution. So I just have to use VPN or change box soon:). This problem will remain definitively a mystery:)
